# How to blend two photos in Mathematica?

Tags: image-processing

The following two photographs *[forest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPKY5.jpg)* and *[tiger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G39md.jpg)* were blended into one with `screen` blending mode in Photoshop. How to accomplish the same result in Mathematica?

[image]

Images:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPKY5.jpg)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G39md.jpg)

Comment: Please post the images "separated" (upload three images)

Comment: The "screen" blending mode is equivalent to the negative of the "multiply" blending mode applied to the negatives of the images, so you can do `ColorNegate[ImageMultiply[ColorNegate[forest], ColorNegate[tiger]]]` and it should be identical to what Photoshop gives.

Comment: Putterboy, please consider switching the Accept to Rahul's answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although I think belisarius's result is prettier your example image clearly has the background visible through the dark parts of the tiger image, and since you wrote that you want "the same result in Mathematica" I propose this as a starting point:

```
{img1, img2} = Import /@
   {"https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPKY5.jpg",
    "https://i.stack.imgur.com/G39md.jpg"};

img2a =
  SetAlphaChannel[
   img2,
   img2 ~ColorSeparate~ "R" ~ImageAdjust~ {0.6, 1}
  ];

Show[{img1, img2a}]
```

[image]

- This method avoids the blown-out highlights of a simple `ImageAdd` operation.
- You can vary the parameters of `ImageAdjust` to tune the blending.  You can also try other channels besides red, or a combination by using `ColorConvert[img2, "Grayscale"]`.

Comment: Ha! Your transparent-stripped got accepted!

Comment: @belisarius And two down-votes from people who didn't actually read the question and look at the example. :^)

Comment: OMG. That deserves retaliative upvoting . +1 in spite of the disservice to the tiger's onine community

Comment: @belisarius Thanks, but I prefer that people do not use votes in that manner.  (Counter other votes, "retaliate," down-vote because a post is "too popular" etc.)  IMO a vote should be determined by a post itself not the way others reacted to the post.

Comment: Ok, Now I'll have to downvote five answers of yours as compensative downvoting :)

Comment: @belisarius While I am sure you are joking FYI (mostly for anyone reading): if you really must reverse a vote you can edit a post which unlocks the "already voted" thing.

Answer (score 12):

```
getBlacks[x_Image] := Binarize[x, .005]
isolateTiger[x_Image] := Erosion[getBlacks[x], 2]
getAreaToChange[tig_Image, fst_Image] := ImageMultiply[fst, Blur[ColorNegate@isolateTiger[tig], 30]]
addImages[tig_Image, fst_Image] := ImageAdd[getAreaToChange[tig, fst], tig]
GraphicsRow[{#, getBlacks@#, isolateTiger@#, getAreaToChange[##], addImages[##]} & @@ {tiger,forest}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

The following is more sophisticated, but the results are better (code partially stolen from [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/example/SimplifyAnImageMask.html))

```
i = tiger;
b = DeleteSmallComponents@FillingTransform@ChanVeseBinarize[i, "TargetColor" -> Black];
skeleton = SkeletonTransform[b];
pruned = Pruning[skeleton, 1, 5];
mask = InverseDistanceTransform[pruned];
ib = Blur[Binarize@mask, 5];
f= ImageAdd[ImageMultiply[ColorNegate@ib, tiger], ImageMultiply[ib, forest]];
GraphicsRow[{i, b, skeleton, pruned, mask, ib, f}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You could have used the images under the links in the question, resolution would be nicer.

Comment: @AlexeyBobrick They weren't posted when I wrote the answer

Answer (score 11):

`ImageAdd` does the job. `Blend` allows you to adjust the blending level.

```
ImageAdd[tiger, background]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I had originally posted this only as a comment, because it was not clear whether the OP wanted something that was exactly like Photoshop's *screen* blending mode, or whether he just wanted to composite the two images together in a nice way like @belisarius's answer. Now that the OP has clarified that a replication of Photoshop's behaviour is indeed desired, I must point out that the accepted answer is not exactly correct.

Photoshop:

[image]

Mr.Wizard's method:

[image]

You can see that they are not identical.

The *screen* blending mode, as [documented by Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/pdf_reference_archives/blend_modes.pdf), combines two images according to the formula $c_{\text{out}} = 1 - (1-c_1)(1-c_2)$. To do this in Mathematica, we can use `ImageApply`:

```
ImageApply[1 - (1 - #1) (1 - #2) &, {forest, tiger}]
```

and the same approach would also work for any other blending mode whose formula you know. For the *screen* blending mode in particular, though, there's a much faster way:

```
ColorNegate[ImageMultiply[ColorNegate[forest], ColorNegate[tiger]]]
```

[image]

As verification, one can check the maximum difference in pixel values between this and the Photoshop result, via `Max@ImageData@ImageDifference[..., ...]`; it is only about $1.6\%$.

Comment: Darn, I somehow overlooked the Screen Blend thing. +1 for the *correct* answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach based on wavelets

```
forest = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPKY5.jpg"];
tiger = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/G39md.jpg"];

swd = StationaryWaveletTransform[#, DaubechiesWavelet[8], 3] & /@ {forest, tiger};

forestVals = swd[[1]][{___, 0 | 1 | 2 | 3}, {"Values",
                      {"Image", "ImageFunction" -> Identity}}];

tigerVals = swd[[2]][{___, 0 | 1 | 2 | 3}, {"Values",
                     {"Image", "ImageFunction" -> Identity}}];

blended = MapThread[ImageAdd[#1, #2] &, {forestVals, tigerVals}];

InverseWaveletTransform[DiscreteWaveletData[
       {{0} -> blended[[1]],
        {1} -> blended[[2]]}], DaubechiesWavelet[8]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

As you can see I have compressed and fused both images in one step - you can always add/remove different wavelet coefficients, use `ImageMultiply` on the parameters in `ImageAdd`, use a different wavelet transform or just a different wavelet family - it's up to you :)

Comment: Wait, the wavelet transform is linear, so adding the wavelet coefficients is equivalent to just adding the pixel values. Indeed your result looks identical to @paw's answer using `ImageAdd` directly on the images.

Comment: @RahulNarain Well, that's the classical algorithm - you can just google that and I am sure thousands of results will pop up. I have used the one I found in "Wavelet analysis and its applications, and active media technology" pt.1  (2004). Sadly, I have this book in my library, but not scanned.. If you want an explanation on how and why this algorithm works - you will have to wait (prepping for finals as we speak)

Comment: I don't understand how your reply addresses my comment. My point was that your method does exactly the same thing as `ImageAdd[forest, tiger]`.

Comment: @RahulNarain Because I wasn't trying to reply to your comment. I was just adding some info :D There's a big difference tho - I can fuse only the details, or the edges, or compress the image (lossy) or lossless, etc, etc

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not an answer but a simple review of the answers given above. [Screen blending mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes#Screen) is equivalent to `Black` passing through, `White` halt, `50% gray` half through. So a picture containing four distinct areas, namely transparent, black, 50% gray and white can be used to test the outcomes of the methods given above. The picture *[tbgw.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rr9EN.png)* below contains an alpha channel, and picture *[bgw.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htqjP.jpg)* contains no alpha channel.

[image]

First, is the output from Photoshop's `screen` blending mode:
[image]

Second, result from ***Paw***'s method by using Mathematica's `AddImage` which refused to add pictures with different channel numbers. So `bgw.jpg` was used for the blending. And please note that the picture was lightened under the gray area. Obviously, the blending effect from `AddImage` is not `screen` instead it is `lighten`.

[image]

Third, result from ***Belisarius***' method: It is a kind of masking rather than blending actually, but the outcome of the answer above is awesome.

[image]

Finally, result from Mr. Wizard's method: It is pretty close to the result from Photoshop. It is really a true `screen` blending method in Mathematica.

[image]

```
{img1, img2} = Import /@
   {"https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPKY5.jpg",
    "https://i.stack.imgur.com/rr9EN.png"};
img2a = SetAlphaChannel[img2, img2~ColorSeparate~"L" ];
Show[{img1, img2a}]
```

Again, clean, short and straight to the point, thank you so much Mr. Wizard.

Comment: I'm glad you have found a method that works for you, but there are a few factual errors in this answer...

Comment: Could you please point them out, I'm glad to know and discuss to make things clear and correct.

Comment: I've posted an answer explaining the main issue. Other factual errors: 1. The *screen* blending mode is not equivalent to "50% grey half through", because *screen* applied to two layers both 50% grey becomes lighter, specifically `GrayLevel[0.75]`. 2. @paw's method is not *lighten* (which is $c_{\text{out}}=\max(c_1,c_2)$) but *add* ($c_{\text{out}}=c_1+c_2$), also known as *linear dodge* in Photoshop.